# How to put some div in row

Tags: html, css, centering

I have some problems with my markup. So, I have HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#wrapper {
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 80%;
}
.item {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 width: 320px;
 height: 200px;
}
```

I suppose that .item divs must be centered in parent #wrapper and #content divs due margin:auto property, but it's doesn't work. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Is your wrapper large enough to have 2 items in a line? The code you have now should work.

Comment: Yes, it's large enough to have 3 block. But they doesn't centered

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the items to be in a row and be able to wrap around. Are you really sure your code isn't working? Your code literally does that. Can you share a fiddle of it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to control it by using media-queries for different resolutions.
Your html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper {
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 100%;
}
#content{
    width:80%;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.item {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
  background:blue;
  border:1px solid #000;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2bCkU/)

For different resolution you have to add media queries and define wrapper width and content width according to them.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) { … }
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { … }
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `display:inline-block` instead of float:left :

```
#wrapper {
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 80%;
 text-align:center;
}
.item {
 display:inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 /* width: 320px; /* not required, you can let width:auto */
 height: 200px;
 text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but in this case .item blocks doesn't transfer to the next line automatically

Comment: do you want to puts your .item in row or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Real cause of your problem is- `float left` of `.item` div. If you remove `float:left` property than they take auto margin.

You want to have your `.item` div centered, not pushed to the left side.
Now that gives you trouble probably, because things don't work out as you'd want them to, because every element you have there, is floated to the left.

You can try for this :

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper { 
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 80%;
 border:1px solid black;
}
.item { 
 margin: auto;
 width: 320px;
 height: 200px;
 border:1px solid black;
}
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/sFFM5/)

Comment: it is not what I want. See, this page will be portfolio page, so I need to 3 blocks in row, which will be transfer to the next line automatically in browser resize

Comment: Css "media query" is the best solution if you want to control over the window size. @sumit answer is useful for resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#content{overflow:hidden;}
```

or

```
#wrapper{overflow:hidden;}
```

You have div's with "float:left" but parent hasn't 'haslayout' property